# Coverity - MessageHandler/HttpClient leak issue

Tags: httpclient, coverity, message-handlers

Coverity sees in the following code that the messageHandler going out of scope, leaks the resource it refers to.

> "System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4"
> .net 6.0

Could you please suggest what I can do here?

```
1. "new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler(){UseCookies = false}" creates a new resource.
2. Assigning: "messageHandler" = resource returned from "new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler(){UseCookies = false}".
                    var messageHandler = config.MessageHandler ?? new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false };
                    
3. Condition "config.UseOAuth", taking false branch.
                    if (config.UseOAuth)
                    {
…
4. Resource "messageHandler" is not closed or saved in "HttpClient".
                    var client = new HttpClient(messageHandler, messageHandler != config.MessageHandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(config.Url) };
                   
5. Condition "!config.UseOAuth", taking true branch.
                    if (!config.UseOAuth)
                    {
                        //add request headers
                    }
6. Variable "messageHandler" going out of scope leaks the resource it refers to.
                    return RestService.For<AClass>(client, AClass.RefitSettings);
                });
        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Coverity lack some information how `HttpClient` looks inside.
It says: `4. Resource "messageHandler" is not closed or saved in "HttpClient".`
Internally `HttpClient` is forwarding your `messageHandler` to it's one base class called `HttpMessageInvoker`, then store it in variable `_handler` and there we can find `Dispose` method

```cs
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && !_disposed)
            {
                _disposed = true;
                if (_disposeHandler)
                {
                    _handler.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

So `messageHandler` is saved inside `HttpClient`

In .NET 6 you don't need to reference package `System.Net.Http` at all as it's available without anything with version `6.0.0`

**Note:** What I wrote here is based on version `6.0.0`

---

I see other issue, if this code is called multiple times and if `HttpClient` takes argument `messageHandler` from `config.MessageHandler`, then if one of those `HttpClient` get disposed other one will contained disposed object, so when you are creating `HttpClient` you have pass `false` as second argument if it's `config.MessageHandler`, or just use `messageHandler != config.MessageHandler`

```cs
var client = new HttpClient(messageHandler, messageHandler != config.MessageHandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(config.Url) };
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I will remove the http package, because as you said it's part of .net 6. Yes, my project is bult with targetFramework net6. Regarding, the second issue, I will try as you have suggested and come with a response.

Comment: Hi @zori! I have added as second param, messageHandler != config.MessageHandler, but still the same error arrises. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Hi @adrianamalea second issue wasn't supposed to resolve `Coverity` report, it was additional thing to mention. About Coverity it looks like false positive to me as `HttpClient` takes ownership of `messageHandler` so there is not leak